# PDepend command not working in CakePHP

Tags: composer-php, pdepend

I am using CakePHP 2.3. And I have installed [PDepend](https://pdepend.org/) through composer.json. Following is code snippet of my composer.json file

```js
"require-dev": {
  "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*",
   "phploc/phploc": "*",
   "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*",
   "phpmd/phpmd" : "@stable",
   "pdepend/pdepend" : "2.2.4",
   "sebastian/phpcpd": "*",
  }
   
"config": {
   "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
 }
```

It is getting installed into Vendor folder of CakePHP folder : **app/Vendor/pdepend**

If I try to execute pdepend command in my project : **pdepend --version** then it says : **pdepend: command not found**

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Linux environment. Use below commands.

```
cd ~/
wget http://static.pdepend.org/php/latest/pdepend.phar
sudo chmod +x pdepend.phar
./pdepend.phar --version
```

This way you will be able to use pdepend command.

If you want it to make it global command use command below

```
sudo cp pdepend.phar /usr/bin/pdepend
```

Now you will be able to use pdepend command anywhere in terminal

Hope this helps.